# Boost Property Tree: read value into char *

Tags: c++, boost, char, boost-propertytree

I'm reading various data from a `ptree`. One of the fields is declared as

```
char * segmentCode;
```

So I'm reading into the segmentCode this way:

```
segmentCode = dataTree.get<char*>("segmentCode");
```

However, it throws an Access Violation. Where did I go wrong?

A workaround is ugly:

```
string tmpStr = dataTree.get<string>("segmentCode");    
segmentCode = strdup(tmpStr.c_str());
```

Comment: My guess is that you probably return an invalid pointer in `dataTree.get<char*>` (i.e. a pointer to a local object declared inside the function, which is being invalidated at the function exit).

Comment: I had many problems doing this myself, and eventually found that reworking the problem so that I could use an `std::string` was far better. However, if you really must, read it in as an `std::string`, then call `c_str()` as you are. Then you must copy the characters in the string and assign those to your resulting pointer or it'll go out of scope.

Comment: Thank you. I really dislike the way strings are handled in pure C, but the data exchange interface is for some reason in C, so I need to deal with char*. 

Sadly, it seems that my workaround is the only way to deal with a 42-year-old programming language.

Answer (score 3):

What's the reasoning for using char * for segmentCode? In a C++ world the preference is to use other objects to manage associated data (e.g., std::string, std::vector<>)

If we look at the ptree.hpp header:

```
/**
  * A property tree with std::string for key and data, and default
  * comparison.
  */
typedef basic_ptree<std::string, std::string> ptree;
```

We can see that ptree uses std::string internally for both its keys and values. This implies that ptree's preferred data format is std::string.

As such the recommendation is to use:

```
std::string segmentCode = dataTree.get<std::string>("segmentCode");
```

This is more efficient than your workaround as the string should only be being copied once (from the ptree). While `strdup` will create yet another copy and then require an explicit call later to `free`.

-

Now as to where that access violation is coming from...

If we have a look at the `basic_tree::get<Type>()` method:

```
/** Shorthand for get_child(path).get_value\<Type\>(). */
template<class Type>
Type get(const path_type &path) const;
```

we see this calls through to `basic_tree::get_value<Type>()`:

```
/** Take the value of this node and attempt to translate it to a
 * @c Type object using the default translator.
 * @throw ptree_bad_data if the conversion fails.
 */
template<class Type>
Type get_value() const;
```

Notice the mention of type translation and a default translator.

Further down the call stack we find the point of access violation is actually within the translation process and can be found in stream_translator.hpp (customize_stream::extract):

```
static void extract(std::basic_istream<Ch, Traits>& s, E& e) {
    s >> e;
    if(!s.eof()) {
        s >> std::ws;
    }
}
```

Using streams in this way is a common technique for generically converting between types. Especially when one of the types being converted to/from is a string.

Problem here is that a `get<char*>` defines the storage type (where we are putting the value) to be a char pointer. From ptree's perspective this is considered to be a complete type that can hold a value, while the translating stream considers this as a pointer to an area of memory that can be written to.

This is the equivalent of:

```
std::istringstream iss("value");
char * p; // uninitialized pointer
iss >> p; // write to some random memory location
```

and is why an access violation occurs.

Again the *Type* being passed to `get<Type>` is expected to be able to hold a complete value.

Comment: Regarding using `std::string` and copying, if the OP don't modify the received string it might be possible to use a constant string reference (i.e. `const std::string&`) and the library and compiler may optimize it to be no copy at all.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it doesn't work, but how about the answer to how to do it without converting to `std:string`?

Comment: `ptree` has already converted and internally stored the parsed values as `std::string` (i.e., readxml). `get` then retrieves this value. If you want to completely avoid the use of `std::string` you'll have to use an alternative library. It's hard to recommend which without knowing what format you are parsing and why `std::string` is not a good fit.